# CathThrob - Add to Cart Form - No Shipping and Tax

Tags: cartthrob

I am running CartThrob 2.2.5. I am trying to exempt a product type from shipping and tax. I found the setting in their documentation but it isn't working (http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/add_to_cart_form/index.html)

Here is the opening tag. Any ideas why it isn't working?

**EDIT:** Updated to include Stash tags.

```
{exp:stash:get_list 
    name="event_list"
    match='#{freebie_last}#' 
    against='this_categories_url' 
    limit='1'
}
    {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form 
        class='form-horizontal' 
        entry_id="{this_entry_id}" 
        tax_exempt="yes"
        shipping_exempt="yes"
        return="wines/wine-cart"
    }               
        ....
    {/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: Where is {this_entry_id} coming from? Should this be {entry_id} instead?

Comment: Did you try upgrading to CT 2.2.9 already?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and have upgraded.  Have you figured this out yet?

Comment: Ballyhoos answer is over a year old but the Cartthrob documentation has not been updated. So thank-you Ballyhoo because you saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `entry_id="{this_entry_id}"` to `entry_id="{entry_id}"`.

If that still doesn't work then try it with `{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart}` instead of `{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I am using this inside Stash. The 'this_entry_id' is really the correct tag that I should be using.

Comment: At first glance there's a lot of plugins in use on that section which may all have an effect. Especially when it comes to parse order. You're setting a Stash list matching a Freebie segment, passing another Stash variable into the Stash list within the CT add to cart form tag. Give it a try without Stash and Freebie first and just hard code the entry_id to test. Does that work?

Comment: I removed the plug-ins and still got the same issue.

Comment: I would try and update to the latest version of CT (2.2.91) and then test again to see if that solves the issue. From your description it looks like more of a bug which may well have been squashed in the most recent updates.

Comment: Yea, that is kind of what I was thinking too. Thanks for the help. If the update doesn't fix it, I will contact their official support.

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version of CartThrob. It is now working, it must have bene a bug. Thanks for the help in the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar issue with the 'add_to_cart' tag, and found the 'bug' was that the naming conventions for the parameters for those options were different to what was stated in the documentation to what was in the code.

The parameters should've been;

```
{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart no_tax="yes" no_shipping="yes"}
```

- Cartthrob build was v2.1.6